# prolog error from classifying a subclass of an atom

Tags: prolog

I'm still learning prolog but am coming across this error.

```
Warning: /usr/local/home/jay275/SDRIVE/cs3500/hw7/part1.pl:23:
    Clauses of bird/1 are not together in the source-file
      Earlier definition at /usr/local/home/jay275/SDRIVE/cs3500/hw7/part1.pl:10
      Current predicate: animal/1
      Use :- discontiguous bird/1. to suppress this message
```

I'm trying to say that if hawk then it is a bird.
If it's a bird then it's a animal... etc..

Here is my code:

```
cat(sylvester).
cat(felix).

dog(spike).
dog(fido).

primate(george).
primate("king kong").

bird(tweety).

hawk(tony).

fish(nemo).

%then Mammal if cat or dog or primate
mammal(X) :- cat(X) ; dog(X) ; primate(X).

%then Animal if mammal or bird or fish
animal(X) :- mammal(X) ; bird(X) ; fish(X).

%then bird if hawk
bird(X) :- hawk(X).
```

EDIT: I don't think this error is actually causing any issues, but I'm just making sure I'm not doing anything incorrect.

EDIT2: TAS answered my question by placing the following code together.

```
bird(tweety).

%then bird if hawk
bird(X) :- hawk(X).

hawk(tony).
```

Comment: There are other predicates between the lines `bird(tweety).` and `bird(X) :- hawk(X).`  Place them in consecutive lines just like you did with dog/1 and cat/1.

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to understand what you mean, but I am trying to do what I think you're talking about and it's still throwing me an error.

Comment: Actually did you mean just throw the bird(X) :- hawk(X). after the bird(tweety). ?

Comment: Yes, exactly :-)

Comment: Okay that was an easy fix... I just always thought I had to keep the bird(tweety)., hawk(tony). and fish(nemo). together and all the other stuff below...? Am I wrong in thinking this

Comment: You should keep the lines that define a predicate together. Enhances readability as your source files grows. If you insist on placing them at different positions you have to use discontiguous/1 as suggested in the warning, in your case `:- discontiguous bird/1.`

Comment: Facts do not need to be kept separate from predicates. After all, a fact such as `dog(spike).` is really the same thing as `dog(spike) :- true.`

Comment: @tas: wanna make this a proper answer?

Comment: @lambda.xy.x: done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message informs you that the clauses of your predicate bird/1 are at different positions in your source file, namely line 10 (`bird(tweety).`) and line 23 (`bird(X) :- hawk(X).`). There are clauses of other predicates between those two lines (hawk/1, fish/1, mammal/1, animal/1), hence the definition of bird/1 is discontiguous.

The standard, ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995, states on clauses:

> #### 7.4.3 Clauses
>
> [...] 
>   All the clauses for a user-defined procedure `P` shall be
>   consecutive read-terms of a single Prolog text unless there
>   is a directive `discontiguous(UP)` directive indicating `P`
>   in that Prolog text.

So that leaves you with two options:

1) You add the suggested directive to your source file:

```
:- discontiguous bird/1.

cat(sylvester).
cat(felix).
.
.
.
```

2) You alter your source file such that the clauses of bird/1 appear in consecutive lines:

```
cat(sylvester).
cat(felix).

dog(spike).
dog(fido).

primate(george).
primate("king kong").

bird(tweety).
%then bird if hawk          % <- moved here from the end of source file
bird(X) :- hawk(X).         % <- moved here from the end of source file

hawk(tony).

fish(nemo).

%then Mammal if cat or dog or primate
mammal(X) :- cat(X) ; dog(X) ; primate(X).

%then Animal if mammal or bird or fish
animal(X) :- mammal(X) ; bird(X) ; fish(X).
```